# How I can to convert my .net WinForms app to Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile

I have a program that edits some files. It use .net 4.0. There is TreeView, TextBoxes and Buttons. It does not use any system features. Mostly it do byte converts, serialization and file saving.

I never coded for mobile platforms and this is totally new for me. Now I need to make my program to run on Microsoft Lumia smartphone with Windows 10 Mobile. Is there any easy way for me to do it? Like simple recompiling with another target framework? I don't want to redesign GUI and etc.

Comment: WinForms and Windows-Mobile are two TOTALLY different UI interfaces and are based on two totally different UI Framework. You need to redesign the GUI.

Comment: Visual studio has a built in android project that uses Xamarin for this. Not sure if your pre existing project can be loaded and GUI is retained then you just need to tweek the codes or there exist some holy converter add ons in visual studio to do this for you.

Comment: @Steve - ouch, that no good at all. Thanks. How to develop for Windows 10 Mobile? I don't see such options in VS 2013 Community.

Comment: This should help out for VS 2013 Community [Cross Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx#NET)

Comment: @P.Pat - thanks, this looks helpful.

Comment: @Kosmos Glad to help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not possible, as the difference's between the 2 products is too great** (e.g. most of the win32/UWP api's are not available on windows phone). However if you want to "repackage" your winforms app for the Universal Windows desktop platform then it is possible.

Microsoft has a toolkit called Windows Bridge. It allows you to repackage existing binaries(which includes winforms) into a Universal windows App. The documentation for converting a winforms app to a Universal Windows App can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root).

**Please note the following requirements/caveats BEFORE repackaging your app**

- the winforms app **has to target the .Net framework 4.6.1**
- the winforms app **may not use elevated mode**
- the UWP app created after conversion **only runs on Windows (10) Desktop**

**Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) for the full requirements**

Comment: Although this is a valuable info, the question was about Windows Mobile (Phone) 10. So Windows Bridge is useless.

Comment: @josef  I wasnt aware of that until I posted my answer... should i remove an answer if the information given was invalid? because i did mention the platforms that can be targeted.

Comment: @josef - Huh? Microsoft says we can run UWP program anywhere, including phones. So you saying it's not the way how I can run my program on phone?

Comment: @kosmos yes, it's true that a **native** UWP app runs everywhere. but your app uses windows forms. forms is reliant on desktop specific dll's that don't exist on your phone. Thats why it won't work.

Comment: The first link tells you can convert a Desktop Forms application to UWP for Desktop. Later it states "you can gradually migrate their code to the Universal Windows Platform to reach every Windows 10 device, including phones, Xbox One and HoloLens.". So I would give it a try if the code is hard to re-write in UWP.

Comment: Read the comments at https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/65841/hands-on-project-centennial-converted-in-one-minute (search for mobile). One issue is that 'deskto' apps mostly target x86 and Windows Mobile is mostly ARM. Another pitfall for thinking about automated conversion from Desktop to UWP for Windows Mobile. Yes, you need two different compiler outputs to run an UWP on X86 and then on ARM.

Comment: Ouch... then this really isn't answer for my question :( And the only answer is "This is not possible".

Comment: @josef I'll correct my answer and try to make it more clear.